# Downloading mp3 file in android

Tags: android, flutter

I am making downloading file with this class on Android.

It is triggered by button.

When pushing button on Android, it opens the window, there are audio related application listed.

(such as spotify, itunes, vlc etc....)

However I want to let user download this as file.

Is it possible?

```
class MobileDownloadService {
  Future<void> download({required String url}) async {
    // requests permission for downloading the file
    bool hasPermission = await _requestWritePermission();
    if (!hasPermission) return;

    // gets the directory where we will download the file.
    var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    // You should put the name you want for the file here.
    // Take in account the extension.
    String fileName = 'tunes.mp3';
    
    // downloads the file
    Dio dio = Dio();
    await dio.download(url, "${dir.path}/$fileName");
    
    // opens the file
    OpenFile.open("${dir.path}/$fileName", type: 'audio/mpeg');
  }

  // requests storage permission
  Future<bool> _requestWritePermission() async {
    await Permission.storage.request();
    return await Permission.storage.request().isGranted;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can download.. Try this https://fluttercorner.com/how-to-download-file-from-url-and-save-in-local-storage-in-flutter/#:~:text=To%20download%20the%20file%20and,it%20in%20our%20specific%20path

Comment: By "downloading", you mean placing it in user's "Downloads" directory?

Comment: You've to stream and write it in your new file...

Comment: @GobuCSG The approach you're suggesting is no longer the recommended one, you should instead use SAF. When OP confirms that this is what they're looking for, I will write a more detailed answer.

Comment: @mfkw1 Oh okay, I am using native kotlin.. I haven't see inputstream that's y i shared that sample 